# HTTP status code in GET Method of REST api design

Tags: rest, go

I am learning about the best practices involved in REST API design and wrote a function which handles the GET /cities HTTP/1.1 query.

This function contains cities which is a struct array that holds the cityname, citycode of multiple cities.

Below is the code

```
func FindCitiesHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8")

    if len(cities) == 0 {
            w.WriteHeader(404)
            return
    }

    if err := json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(cities); err != nil {
            /* what to do here? */
    }

    w.WriteHeader(200)
```

}

Now when I started thinking about  the possible outcomes of this function. I found these situations.

1. It returns all the cities properly as JSON response successfully. So I return 200 http status.
2. The list of cities is empty. So there is nothing to return. So I return 404 (resource not found)
3. It is about to return JSON response of all cities, but something gone wrong during JSON encoding. Now I am confused here, how do I deal with this situation.

I mean how do you convey message properly to user, if

1. If your business/application logic had some error/exception.
2. If data access logic found some issues. (say connection to database is not reachable)

Could you guys please help me to suggest best practices you followed in these situations?

Comment: Well, for server side problems you have the 5xy status codes. Regarding 404 if len(cities)==0: This seems wrong. 404 is "resource not found", but the resource _was_ _found_, it just happens that the resource does not contain cities. Think of the difference between "There is no such file 'foobar'." and "Here is the content of file 'foobar' (but foobar happens to be empty)."

Comment: You should use response code 204 in case if request was processed successfully, but response is empty: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#2xx_Success

Comment: You should use the [http constants](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#pkg-constants) instead of the return code. Example: `w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)`

Comment: Thanks everybody 
@volker. Actually for 404 code. Just an extended question. Suppose if I search a city by its code and it is not found. Then what should be the return http code?

Comment: @Neeraj Assuming you do a GET /api/cities/31022 and there is no Dudley than 404 is fine. If you do a GET /api/cities?filterByCode=31022 than 404 seems out of place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. 200 is correct
2. 404 is probably *not* correct; A list of cities can be empty, and still exist. (Think: A 0-length array is still an array.) You should probably return 200.  You would only return 404 if the list of cities doesn't exist on your server (in other words, that should probably never happen with your API).
3. If you experience an internal server error, such as with marshaling JSON, you should return an Internal Server Error, status 500.